# SQL Server, Días laborales tomando el sábado como medio día

Tags: sql, sql-server, funciones

Estoy realizando una función que me calcula los días laborales, tomando en cuenta que dónde trabajo se trabaja de lunes a sábado(pero medio día). El trabajo de lunes a sábado ya está hecho, sin embargo, tengo que considerar el medio día del sábado, que es dónde me encuentro atascado.

Ejemplo: de Lunes a sábado serían 5.5 días de trabajo, en lugar de 6

Adjunto código que estoy realizando. Espero me puedan orientar al respecto

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[WorkingDays](@StartDate DATETIME,@EndDate DATETIME) 
RETURNS INT 
AS 
BEGIN

    DECLARE @WorkingDays INT = 0
    DECLARE @DiferenciaDias INT = 0
    DECLARE @Cont INT = 0
    DECLARE @DiaSemana DATETIME

    SELECT @DiferenciaDias = DATEDIFF(DAY,@StartDate,@EndDate) + 1

    BEGIN
    WHILE @Cont < @DiferenciaDias 
        BEGIN
            SELECT @DiaSemana = @StartDate + @Cont
            IF ((DATEPART(dw,@DiaSemana) != 1)
                BEGIN
                    SELECT @WorkingDays = @WorkingDays + 1 
                END
                    SELECT @Cont = @Cont + 1 
            END 
        END 

    RETURN (@WorkingDays) 
END
```

Comment: Pero si quieres contar el sabado como medio dia deberias  validar si el sabado, el mayor o igual alas 12:00 AM y si encaso es asi deberas agregarle .5 a la variable contadora

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declara tu variable @WorkingDays como un Numeric(4, 2), sin ella no vas a poder sumar los decimales.

Luego utiliza el siguiente While:

```
--  Loop desde la fecha inicio hasta tu fecha fin, al ser un DATETIME, le sumo un día y utilizo el comparador "menor que <"
WHILE @StartDate < DATEADD(DAY, 1, @EndDate)
BEGIN
    --  Cuentas los días, bajo una condición en el día sabado, DW(Day of the week), 7 = Sabado.
    SET @WorkingDays = @WorkingDays + CASE WHEN DATEPART(DW, @StartDate ) = 7 THEN 0.5 ELSE 1 END

    -- Sumas un día a la variable de fecha inicio.
    SET @StartDate = DATEADD(DAY, 1, @StartDate);
END

--  Retornas la variable que ha sumado tus días.
RETURN @WorkingDays
```

Saludos.

Comment: El ejemplo de @Rostan me funcionó, solo que no lo hice tal cual lo explica.

Comment: @VLT que bueno que te haya funcionado, no olvides marcar como resuelta la pregunta con esta respuesta para cerrarla. Y si puedes, edita tu pregunta y adjunta como lo resolviste. Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Una forma alternativa que permite evitar el uso de los ciclos, es hacer un poco de aritmética para calcular los días:

```
DECLARE @FromDate   DATETIME
DECLARE @ToDate     DATETIME
DECLARE @Sabados    INT
DECLARE @Domingos   INT
DECLARE @DiasResto  INT

SELECT  @FromDate   = '2018-03-01',
    @ToDate         = '2018-03-07'

SELECT  @Sabados    = DATEDIFF(DAY, -2, @ToDate)/7-DATEDIFF(DAY, -1, @FromDate)/7
SELECT  @Domingos   = DATEDIFF(DAY, -1, @ToDate)/7-DATEDIFF(DAY,  0, @FromDate)/7
SELECT  @DiasResto  = DATEDIFF(DAY, @FromDate, DATEADD(DAY,1, @ToDate)) - @Sabados - @Domingos

SELECT  @Sabados                    AS 'Sabados', 
        @Domingos                   AS 'Domingos', 
        @DiasResto                  AS 'Resto', 
        @DiasResto + (@Sabados *.5) AS 'Calculo'
```

En este caso calculamos los días entre dos fechas (recordar que el `DATEDIFF` no resulta inclusivo con la fecha superior), los sábados y los domingos, luego simplemente sumaremos 0.5 a los sábados y 1 al resto de los días que no son sábado ni domingo.

**Importante**: Esta rutina tiene como base de calculo el `01/01/1900` que fue lunes, por lo que no sirve para calcular rangos que incluyan fechas anteriores.

Comment: No creo que te sume el .5 porque la variable sábados es de tipo int y no te va a poder poner el .5 te lo va a redondear a 1

Comment: @Frankenstainero, no, SQL Server hace una coerción implícita en estos casos (al multiplicar un entero por 0.5), el problema podría ocurrir si asignas ese resultado a un variable entera.

Comment: osea que si en ese caso los días trabajados son 2 semanas, entonces me contaría 11 días trabajados, si es así estas en lo correcto.

Comment: @Frankenstainero, si efectivamente hace eso. El ejemplo en la respuesta es del caso planteado por el OP, dónde suma 5.5.

Comment: gracias, por la aclaración